# Mobile device heat up. What time before it heats up is considered good? Android/IOS Unity

Tags: unity, android, performance, ios

could not find anything that answers this in a detailed way ?

I managed to optimise the game to the point that the device heat up(real heat up and frame drop) only after 90 min of continuous gameplay. Is that good ?

Tested on Samsung s9, and the game targets OpenGLES 3.1, it probably does not matter but still.

Thank you!

Comment: I would likely uninstall a game that makes my phone heat up.

Comment: This is a subjective question, and can't really be answered because different devices will heat up at different rates. @Vaillancourt Many modern flagship phones have CPUs that, when running at full power, will produce more heat than passive cooling can deal with. Unless things have changed recently, with performance-intensive games, this can get you stuck in a cycle where the game runs smoothly for a few minutes while the phone gets hot, then the performance drops as thermal throttling kicks in, then repeat once the phone is cool enough for throttling to end.

Comment: Some games can cause a phone to heat up within minutes. Different people have different opinions on this. The obvious answer is, the less heat there is the better, but that's not always feasible. There is no one time frame that is a correct answer, so I don't think you'll be able to get any accurate answer on this.

Comment: Any suggestions on this topic are good

Comment: @Kevin Yes, the pattern seems annoying. My point is that I understand that a device heating up is generally viewed as bad for the battery. As TomTsagk points out, I'm probably not the target audience for this kind of game as I'd like to preserve the life of my battery as much as possible.